# Deleting extension only from the first column

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I have a file like this with tab separated two columns:

```
 ENSG00000242268.2    0.07563
 ENSG00000270112.3    0.09976
 ENSG00000167578.15   4.38608
 ENSG00000273842.1    0.0
 ENSG00000078237.5    4.08856
```

I would like to remove the numeric extensions from the end in the 1st column, so the output will be:

```
 ENSG00000242268    0.07563
 ENSG00000270112    0.09976
 ENSG00000167578    4.38608
 ENSG00000273842    0.0
 ENSG00000078237    4.08856
```

Simply doing `sed 's/\..*$//'` returns only first column value and using awk with field separator `'.'` , `awk -F'.'` removes the values from second column too as there are decimal numbers.

A similar question has been answered here:
[removing extensions in a column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168494/removing-extensions-in-a-column)

I am still not being able to delete just from column 1st only.

Comment: Does every line start with a space?

Comment: With TAB between columns use - sed 's/(.[0-9]\+)\t/\t/' file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'\t' '{sub(/\..+$/,"",$1)}1' OFS='\t' file
```

- `-F'\t'` - field separator
- `sub(/\..+$/,"",$1)` - removes `.` with following chars from the 1st field at once

The output:

```
ENSG00000242268 0.07563
ENSG00000270112 0.09976
ENSG00000167578 4.38608
ENSG00000273842 0.0
ENSG00000078237 4.08856
```

---

Or with simple ***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/\.[0-9]*//' file
```

Answer (score 5):

just do:

```
sed 's/\(.[0-9]\+\) / /'
```

it will only match the first decimal part and delete it.

on your sample:

```
echo "ENSG00000242268.2    0.07563
>  ENSG00000270112.3    0.09976
>  ENSG00000167578.15   4.38608
>  ENSG00000273842.1    0.0
>  ENSG00000078237.5    4.08856" | sed 's/\(.[0-9]\+\) / /'
ENSG00000242268    0.07563
ENSG00000270112    0.09976
ENSG00000167578   4.38608
```

edit if you have tabs then try this:

```
sed 's/\(.[0-9]\+\)\( \|\t\)\2/'
```

Comment: This is doing exactly opposite on my data. This is removing the everything after '.' from second column and not on first column.

Comment: This command will not work if used TAB between columns

Comment: I have edited in my original question, in my file both columns are tab separated

Comment: yeah that is most likely what is happening.

Comment: @Kusalananda method works too :) if you know that the ENSG.... pattern is exactly that it is a better, more precise matching solution.

Comment: @Roli I updated my pattern to account for tabs. :) like my comment says above if the pattern ENSG followed by 11 digits then Kusalananda's solution is more precise.

Comment: no sense to put captured group here `sed 's/\(.[0-9]\+\) / /' ` if it's not used

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you are correct. I typed it fast :) I think I was going to go more the route Kusalananda did, but changed my mind in the middle

Answer (score 4):

We may match [a versioned Ensembl human gene "stable" ID](https://www.ensembl.org/info/genome/stable_ids/index.html) with the extended regular expression `ENSG[0-9]{11}\.[0-9]+`.

Using this with `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/(ENSG[0-9]{11})\.[0-9]+/\1/' file.in >file.out
```

This does not rely on the delimiter between columns or where on the line the identifier occurs.

Comment: Thanks you so much and for the regular expression too. very helpful.

Comment: @Roli You're welcome. Note too that if you're using the Ensembl Perl API for coding, you do not need to remove the versions from the identifiers. Also, if you publish something with a list of Ensembl stable IDs, it's better to keep the versions (so that a reader knows _exactly_ what gene sequence you looked at). Ether that, or be careful to mention what Ensembl release you used. (And don't forget to [cite Ensembl](http://www.ensembl.org/Help/Faq?id=392) too!)

Answer (score 0):

With Bash using [substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file='file.txt'

while read -r i; do

  a=$( <<< "${i}" cut -d $'\t' -f 1 )
  a=${a%.*}
  b=$( <<< "${i}" cut -d $'\t' -f 2- )

  printf '%s\t%s\n' "${a}" "${b}"

done < "${file}"
```

Comment: Tabs are already the default delimiter for `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[\t.]' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1,$3 "." $4}'
ENSG00000242268 0.07563
ENSG00000270112 0.09976
ENSG00000167578 4.38608
ENSG00000273842 0.0
ENSG00000078237 4.08856
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perl** solution:

`perl -pe 's/\.\d+//`

- `\.\d+` matches the first '.' followed by 1 or more digit.
- `s/pattern//` will delete the selected pattern.